How to set up CLion Docker Toolchain path mapping on Windows?
I’m trying to configure CLion to mount my project directory into /project inside a Docker container. According to this CLion documentation, by default, the project folder is mounted into the /tmp directory in the container for build/run/debug tasks. However, if path mappings are set in the toolchain, CLion will use those mappings instead.
My project directory is \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\user\CLion\project, and I want to map this to /project inside the Docker container.
I tried setting the Virtual machine path and Local path in the toolchain path mappings, but I am confused about what to specify for each. After reading more documentation, particularly this page, I got more confused about whether the Virtual machine path refers to the path in the WSL (which I use as the Docker backend) or the path inside the Docker container. Similarly, should the Local path be the WSL filesystem path (\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\user\CLion), or something else?
Could anyone clarify what values I should enter to achieve my goal of mounting the project into /project inside the container?
Thanks for any help you can provide!
